# Wrong direction in electric field of a linear charge

Tags: calculus, physics

I have a big doubt about direction of electric field. When I try to compute a Electric Field over a point at (0,2) from the linear charge in the $x$ axis from (-5,0) to (0,0) with a density linear charge $\sigma=+20 $nC/m`, the Electric Field is $\vec{E}=-55.6i+83.55j$. This $-55.6i$ don't let me fall sleep. Question : Why the "minus" sign?, must the vector $\vec{E}$ be $\vec{E}=+55.6i+83.55j$ because the linear charge is positive?,

$dq = \sigma*ds$

$\overset{\to }{u}=\frac{\left(x\overset{\to }{i}+2\overset{\to }{j}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+2^2}}$

$\text{dE}=\frac{\text{dq}}{4 r^2 \pi \epsilon _o}\overset{\to }{u}$

$\frac{\sigma }{4 \pi \epsilon _o}\int _{-5}^0\frac{1}{\left(x^2+2^2\right)^{3/2}}dx*\left(x\overset{\to }{i}+2\overset{\to }{j}\right)=-55.6i+83.55j$

Comment: By the way, the close votes (not from me) are probably because you didn't embed your image in the question itself or format your math expressions with Mathjax. If you don't correct these, there is a chance the question will be closed.

Comment: Really thank you for the advice, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation has a sign error.

If you consider the $x$ component of the electric force on the unit positive charge, it will be given by:

$\displaystyle dF_x = k\frac{e\sigma dx}{4+x^2} \cos \theta = k\frac{e\sigma dx}{4+x^2} \frac {|x|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}} = k\frac{e\sigma dx}{4+x^2} \frac {-x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}} \\= - ke\sigma x(4+x^2)^{-\frac 32}dx$

because, for that range of $x$ values, the absolute value $|x|$ is given by $-x$. Once you do this, you should get the correct answer.

(By the way, $\theta$ is the angle, measured counterclockwise of the electric force vector on the unit charge from the horizontal axis, $e$ is the magnitude of a unit charge (you divide this away for the electric field strength), $\sigma$ is the charge density, a constant, and $k$ is the usual constant of proportionality involving $\pi$ and the permittivity $\varepsilon_0$).

Comment: Really thank you, but considering the linear charge is positive, would not the $\overset{\to }{E}$ components be positives, too?

Comment: @Fernando Yes they would, both of them. That's my point. You made a sign error. My answer has the correct sign. After you integrate and evaluate for the bounds, the result is positive for the $x$ component.